# First occurence of an event in a log table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a log table:
user_id, path_id, poi_id, timestamp, event_type

It's like a beacon database in a museum, but instead it's part of an audio tour system, where people can select different paths inside the same venue.

example:

```
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour,Beacon_1, 2015-05-05 11:49, "WentAcross"
Zoe, An adventure in the Lion's Lair, Beacon_15, 2015-05-05 11:50, "WentAcross"
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour, Beacon_3, 2015-05-05 11:50, "WentAcross"
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour, Beacon_4, 2015-05-05 11:51, "WentAcross"
Kyle, Strolling at the Zoo Tour,Beacon_4, 2015-05-05 11:51, "WentAcross"
Zoe, An adventure in the Lion's Lair, Beacon_15, 2015-05-05 11:50, "WentAcross"
Zoe, An adventure in the Lion's Lair, Beacon_1, 2015-05-05 11:51, "WentAcross"
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour, Beacon_6, 2015-05-05 11:51, "WentAcross"
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour, Beacon_5, 2015-05-05 11:52, "WentAcross"
John, Strolling at the Zoo Tour, Beacon_2, 2015-05-05 11:53, "WentAcross"
```

I want to know how many times was a poi first touched for a certain user by timestamp inside a path.

In this example, the result should be:

- Beacon_1 1 (was touched as first point by John, for Zoe, it wasn't
  first... can be that the path crossed, or simply joined elsewhere)
- Beacon_15 2 (was touched as first point by Zoe and Kyle in Lion's
  Lair tour)
- Beacon_4 1 (was touched as first point in Strolling around
  the Zoo tour by Zoe - she connected mid-way it seems)

Every other Beacon_ID should read zero.

How could I build such a query?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How do you define "first touched"?

Comment: @Barmar: by timestamp

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result. One example line is not enough to understand the question in general. Try showing a table with about 10 input rows and all the output that should result.

Comment: Hey Aadaam, I downvoted because I think your sample results have a few errors (who's Joe?)

Comment: @samthebrand: typo corrected. Ended up using good old imperative solution, select everything then process line-by-line in conventional programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Being your table  columns something like 'name', 'beacon', 'timestamp' and the tablename 'events'... I have in mind a temporary table... Something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(evt.name), tmp_evt.beacon, tmp_min_ts, COUNT(1) as touching
FROM events evt 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT evt.beacon AS beacon, MIN(timestamp) AS min_ts
   FROM events evt
   GROUP BY evt.beacon
 ) tmp_evt ON (tmp_evt.min_ts = evt.timestamp AND tmp_evt.beacon = evt.beacon)
GROUP BY tmp_evt.beacon
```

Comment: The question we are looking for answer is "how many users did join the given tour on that point", and I somehow miss the user from this query, but thanks!

Comment: Ok, my fault with English. 

Even so, I this case I was thinking about user at  "evt.name" field. My fault.  If you want to count the different number of users joined at each point (or beacon at my sample)...

I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what you're actually asking would this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), timestamp
FROM log_table
WHERE user_id = 123
AND poi_id = 321
AND path_id BETWEEN 123 AND 321
GROUP BY timestamp;
```